# Excelのシェイプのフォント色が自動かどうかの判別

Tags: vba

エクセルマクロにて、
シェイプのフォント色が「自動」かどうかを判別しようとしています。
以下のように、ColorIndexがxlColorIndexAutomaticの場合、フォント色を「自動」と判断していますが、
Excel上でカラーパネルより、フォント色に黒（Colorコードは0）を設定した場合も、ColorIndexがxlColorIndexAutomaticとなる為、黒と「自動」が区別できない状態です。
判別方法があれば教えてください。

```
If ActiveSheet.Shapes(0).TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic Then
・・・省略・・・
End If
```

Comment: 逆にプログラムで明示的に`ColorIndex`に`1`・`Color`に`RGB(0,0,0)`を設定後にSave、再Openして値がどうなるか試してみてはどうでしょう？ それが`xlColorIndexAutomatic(-4105)`に変わってしまうなら仕様でしょうし、変わらないなら手作業のミスや思い違いか、手作業では何か制限があるか、と言うことなのではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

回答ありがとうございます。
自動については以下で判別するようにしました。

```
shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.ClorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic And
shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Fill.ForceColor.ObjectForceColor = msoNotThemeColor
```

Answer (score 0):

シェイプのフォントの色の「自動」とFont.Colorで黒の判別してみました。
同じ振る舞いをするので、仕様のようですね。

```
Sub macro1()
Dim sp As Shape
Set sp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
sp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = 0
If ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic Then
sp.TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3
End If
End Sub
```